# Is it possible to change the Alt value inside the image.html.twig template?

Tags: 8

Is it possible to change the *alt* value inside the image.html.twig template?
I found out that it can be accessed via `attributes.alt`. And then there is a protected value. Is there a way to set it?

Something like:

`{% set attributes.alt.value = 'new alt' %}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Twig template you can use the method [attributes.setAttribute()](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/using-attributes-in-templates#s-attributessetattributeattribute-value):

```
{% set attributes = attributes.setAttribute('alt', 'new alt') %}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. in your theme folder create **{theme_name}.theme**
2. in your **{theme_name}.theme** use the fllowing function to alter any image attribute ex (alt):

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK
 */
function YourThemeName_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
  $variables['attributes']['alt'] = 'new alt value';
}
```